# How can I make a countdown that checks every one second if something was inputed, without interruption

Tags: c++

I am making a game called Keyboard Trainer for my class, and I got a problem, i want to make a loop, that counts from 5 to 0, and checks every one number if something was inserted, like a character, but in my code, it just counts from 5 to 0 without any reaction to inputs, I want to make that it would react to it, but it wouldn't do anything to the countdown.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void countdown(){
    for (int o = 5; o >= 0 ; o--)//Countdown timeris, kuris skaiciuoja nuo 5 iki 0
    {
        cout << o << " ";//Isveda timerio duomenis
        Sleep(1000);//Palaukia 1 sekunde
    }
}

int main(){
    int ivestas_kl, sugeneruotas_kl, ats_neats = 0, taip_ne, Y_N, i = 0,   ats = 0, neats = 0;
    string taip;
    cout << "Sveiki atvyke i Klaviaturos Treniruokli!\n";
    cout << "Ar norite pradeti zaidima?(Y/N)?\n" << "Kai paspausite Y, jums atsiras  zaidimo taisykles.\n\n";
    Y_N = _getch();
    if (Y_N == 121)//Patikrina ar Y_N yra Y raide
    {
        while (Y_N != 110 && i % 2 == 0)//Jei Y_N nera N ir i padalinus is 2  nelieka liekanos
        {
            i++;
            cout << "\tTaisykles\n";
            cout << "\t-------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
            cout << "\t|Sio zaidimo metu, jus turesite paspausti atsitiktinai sugeneruota|\n\t|klavisa siam tikslui jus turesite 5s. Jei suspesite ji paspausti,|\n\t|jus gausite viena taska ir sitaip taskai bus pridedami po du, jei|\n\t|nesuklysdami atspesite kelis is eiles, bet jei neatspesite vieno,|\n\t|taskai vel prisides po viena ir taip kas 2 spejimus.Trukme- 1min.|\n";
            cout << "\t-------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
            cout << "Pradeti zaidima?(taip)\t";
            cin >> taip;

            while (Y_N != 27 && taip == "taip")//Kol Y_N nera ESC ir taip yra lygus taip
            {
                system("cls");
                sugeneruotas_kl = rand() % 78 + 48;//Sugeneruoja betkoki skaciu nuo 48 iki 126
                char kl = char(sugeneruotas_kl);//Konvertuoja is int i char
                cout << "Spauskite " << kl << " !\n\n";//Parodo koki klavisa paspausti
                countdown();
                ivestas_kl = _getch();//Paima ivesta simboli
                char konv_ivestas_kl = char(ivestas_kl);//Konvertuoja int i char
                if (ivestas_kl != 0 && konv_ivestas_kl == kl)//Jei ivestas_kl nera lygus 0 ir konv_ivestas_kl yra lygus ivestam ir jei timerio laikas nesibaige
                {
                    ats++;
                    cout << "\nTeisingai!\n\n" << "Norint baigti zaidima spauskite ESC.\n";
                    break;
                }
                else if (konv_ivestas_kl != kl)
                {
                    neats++;
                    cout << "\nNespejote.\n\n";
                    break;
                }//Else if pabaiga
            }//For pabaiga
            Y_N = _getch();
        }
    }//While pabaiga
}//Pirmo if pabaiga
```

Comment: As best I know, there is no standard, portable way to do this.  Most compilers/environment supply a way to do it, but it will depend on your setup.  Describe your environment details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool countdown()
{
  for (int o = 5; o >= 0 && !_kbhit(); o--)
  {
    cout << o << " ";
    Sleep(1000);
  }

  return _kbhit();
}
```

Usage:

```
ivestas_kl = countdown() ? _getch() : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

***You could experiment with a combination*** of `GetAsyncKeyState()` and `clock()`.  Using these C functions,  you can ***1)*** define a third function to test whether any key is down (or has been recently hit), ***2)*** test that event (or lack of event) against elapsed time.  With these capabilities you should be able to what you described.

***Below is a simple example*** program that does both:

***EDIT*** modified to test for key down *NOW* or key *recently* hit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ansi_c.h>

BOOL isAnyKeyDown(void);ghh
int main(void) {
    clock_t t;
    float elapsed;

    t = clock();
    while (1) 
    {
        if (isAnyKeyDown()) 
        {
            //key entered, reset timer and do stuff
            printf("less than one second");
            break;//of course you can do something besides break, this here just for demonstration
        }
        Sleep(10);
        t = clock() - t;
        elapsed = ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        if(elapsed > 1) 
        {
            printf("longer than one second");
            break;//(see comment above)
        }
    }                                      
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

BOOL isAnyKeyDown(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=8;i<255;i++)
    {   //check both MSB and LSB for keydown NOW, and Key recently hit
        if((0x80000000 & GetAsyncKeyState(i) != 0) || (0x00000001 & GetAsyncKeyState(i) != 0)) return TRUE; 
    }

    return FALSE;   
}
```

Comment: `(0x80000000 & GetAsyncKeyState(i) != 0) || (0x00000001 & GetAsyncKeyState(i) != 0)` seems like a lot more work than `(0x80000001 & GetAsyncKeyState(i)) != 0`.

Comment: @kfsone - No arguments.  From the way I read the _[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)_, your suggestion of checking both bits simultaneously will work to provide the same logic I have coded, but more efficiently.